# org-bullets-mode doesn't activate at start up

Tags: org-mode

Since installing a new GNU-Linux distribution (MX), org-bullets-mode does not activate automatically when I open my documents. I have to activate it manually (M-x org-bullets-mode). Yet, I haven't changed anything in my previous configuration (init.el and config.org) and everything was working fine before. I have explored topics on the site and haven't found anything specifically on this subject. Thank you for pointing me towards a possible solution.

grep "org-bullets-mode" config.org

```lisp
    (add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (org-bullets-mode 1)))
    :hook (org-mode . org-bullets-mode)
```

My init.el:

```lisp
    (org-babel-load-file
    (expand-file-name "config.org" user-emacs-directory))
```

And the part concerning org-bullets-mode in my config.org:

#+begin_src emacs-lisp

```lisp
    (require 'org-bullets)
    (add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (org-bullets-mode 1)))
```

#+end_src

#+begin_src emacs-lisp

```lisp
    (use-package org-bullets
    :after org
    :hook (org-mode . org-bullets-mode)
    :custom
    (org-bullets-bullet-list '("◉" "○" "●" "○" "●" "○" "●")))
```

#+end_src

Comment: Can you find the place in `init.el` where you activate the mode? Just `grep` for `org-bullets-mode` in `init.el/config.org` and see if it's still there.

Comment: Maybe try [org-superstar-mode](https://github.com/integral-dw/org-superstar-mode). B.t.w. after installing the package, due to autoload (and the org-mode-hook), you only need a single line in your config: (add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'org-superstar-mode). And please take some time for formatting your question. Quickly check the edit to get an idea how to. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you, but tried org-superstar-mode and had the same result: org-bullets-mode or org-superstar-mode does not load at start up. I had to do it manualy